# Trigonometric formula coming from hypergeometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, hypergeometric-function

While playing with hypergeometric functions, I numerically stumbled upon the identity:
$$\mathrm{cos}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6} - \dfrac{1}{6} \mathrm{arctan}\left( \dfrac{3\sqrt{15}}{11} \right) \right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{10} + 3\sqrt{2}}{8}$$
Is this identity true? Well-known?

Comment: well, sine and cosine of the arctan piece is straightforward, then some serious effort to include the $1/6.$ So, the trig functions are, well, cosmetic. Also, recall formula for $\cos (a-b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct,
$$ \cos \arctan\left( \frac{3\sqrt{15}}{11} \right) = \frac{11}{16} \; , \; $$
$$ \cos \frac{1}{6} \arctan\left( \frac{3\sqrt{15}}{11} \right) = \frac{\sqrt {18 + 6 \sqrt 5}}{4 \sqrt 2} \; , \; $$
$$ \sin \frac{1}{6} \arctan\left( \frac{3\sqrt{15}}{11} \right) = \frac{{3 - \sqrt 5}}{4 \sqrt 2} \; , \; $$
Takes a while. The cosine with the 1/6 is a root of
$$  512 c^6 - 768 c^4 + 288 c^2 - 27 = (8 c^2-3)(64 c^4 - 72 c^2 +9) $$

Comment: great! thank you!